# Why is the $\nabla g\neq0$ condition needed for the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Based on my Calculus textbook, the method of Lagrange multipliers is stated as follow:

Suppose that $f(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)$ are differentiable and $\nabla g \ne \mathbf 0$ when $g(x,y,z) = 0$. To find the local extremum values of $f$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y,z) = 0$, find the values of $x,y,z$ and $\lambda$ simultaneously satisfying the equations $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ and $g(x,y,z) = 0$.

My questions are:

1. Why do we need $\nabla g \ne \mathbf 0$ in the assumption? (Is there something realted to the implicit function theroem?)
2. What happens if $\nabla g = \mathbf 0$?

Comment: If you have $g(x,y,z) = 0$ and $\nabla g(x,y,z) = 0$ for all $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ then $g(x,y,z)$ is the null function.

Comment: Suppose $g$ isn't null. Is it possible that $P$ is an extremum of $f$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y,z)=0$ while $\nabla g(P) = \mathbf 0$?

Comment: Make $g(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z)$ . Now if $P$ is a local extremum  $\nabla f(P) = \lambda \nabla g(P) = 0$ In this case is possible.

Comment: So by letting $f = g$, the original optimization problem are transformed into finding local extrema of $f$ without any constraint. I think I've understood the case that for a non-null function, it is possible that $\nabla g(P) = 0$ and $P$ is an extremum.

Comment: On the other hand, supposing that $g$ is not null, is there any geometric interpretation of the assumption $\nabla g \ne \mathbf 0, \forall (x,y,z) : g(x,y,z)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to understand the condition is to see what can go wrong when $\nabla g=0$. Try working through the following examples:

---

Apply Lagrange's method to the following problem and then solve it graphically:

$$\min_{x,y} x^2 +y^2\text{ subject to $(x−1)^3 −y^2 = 0$}$$

---

Apply the method to
$$\max_{x,y} y−2x^2 +x\text{ subject to $(x+y)^2 = 0$}$$
and compare your findings  to the equivalent problem:

$$\max_{x,y} y−2x^2 +x\text{ subject to $x+y = 0$}$$

Comment: In problem 1, I get $\nabla g(x,y) = (3x^2 - 6x + 3, -2y)$ and $(1,0)$ is the only extremum. Also, $\nabla g(1,0) = (0, 0)$.

In problem 2.1, $\nabla g(x,y) = (2x+2y, 2x+2y)$, $(1,0)$ is the only extremum, and $\nabla g(1,0) = (0, 0)$. While in problem 2.2, though equivalent to problem 2.1, $\nabla g(x,y) = (1,1), \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, $(1,0)$ is the only extremum, and $\nabla g(1, 0) = (1,1)$.

Comment: It seems that $P$ can be an extremum, even if the constraint function $g$ satisfying $\nabla g(P) = \mathbf 0$.

Comment: So I guess it is save to drop out the assumption $\nabla g = \mathbf 0$.

Comment: You are right that $(1,0)$ is the solution to the first problem. I think you meant $(0,0)$, rather than $(1,0)$, is the solution to the second problem.

Comment: If you apply Lagrange's method to problem 1, then you will not find any stationary points of the Lagrangean, i.e. you will not find a solution $(x,y,\lambda)$ to $\nabla f(x,y)=\lambda \nabla g(x,y)$. Problem 1 shows that $\nabla f(x,y)=\lambda \nabla g(x,y)$ is not a necessary condition for a (local) minimizer if the constraint qualificaiton ($\nabla g(x,y)\neq 0$) is not satisfied. In problem 2, the constraint curve has a cusp at the solution, so does not define $x$ or $y$ as an implicit function of the other variable near the solution.

Comment: In both 2.1 and 2.2 the constraint curve does define $y$ as an implicit function of $x$ ($y=-x$). However, in problem 2.1 the constraint qualification is not satisfied, but in problem 2.2. Lagrange's method works fine for problem 2.2, but not 2.1 (there is no stationary point of the Lagrangean in problem 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Let me consider again some of the examples discussed in the other answer, but working out the details of the calculations.

---

- Considering the optimisation problem $\max_{x,y} (y-x^2)$ subject to the constraint $x+y=0$. Graphically, the solution is straightforward, and we can also just substitute $y=-x$ into the cost, which then reads $-x-x^2$, and easily find out that it maximises at $x=-1/2$.

  Same answer is obtained via Lagrange's multipliers: computing the gradients of cost and constraint we have
  $$\begin{pmatrix}-2x\\1\end{pmatrix} = \lambda \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix},$$
  which has the only solution $x=-1/2$.
- Let's consider now the completely equivalent problem $\max_{x,y}(y-x^2)$ subject to $(x+y)^2=0$. The constraint is clearly equivalent, and thus so is the solution, however, if we now follow the Lagrange multipliers scheme we get
  $$\begin{pmatrix}-2x\\1\end{pmatrix} = 2\lambda(x+y)\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
  But this system now doesn't have any solution in the feasible set. To see it, observe that the components on the LHS must be equal, thus $x=-1/2$, but on the RHS $x+y=0$, which is a contradiction. We conclude that the Lagrange multipliers approach doesn't capture the local maximum at $x=-y=-1/2$ in this case.

---

- For another even simpler example, say we want to find $\min x$ subject to $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$. The solution is clearly $x=0$, which you see because the constraint is a unit-radius circle with center $(1/2,0)$. Lagrange gives the condition $\binom{1}{0}=\lambda\binom{2(x-1)}{2y}$, which has solution $y=0$ and $\lambda(x-1)=1/2$.
  In the feasible set for $y=0$ we can have $x=0$ or $x=2$, both of which are viable solution corresponding to $\lambda=-1/2$ and $\lambda=1/2$, respectively (one of these corresponds to the min and the other to the max).

  Now let's do this again but with the constraint written as $[(x-1)^2+y^2]^2=1$. The Lagrange condition becomes
  $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} = 2\lambda[(x-1)^2+y^2]\begin{pmatrix}2(x-1)\\ 2y\end{pmatrix}.$$
  But on the feasible set the RHS is identically zero, thus there is no solution.